# $wpdb insert multiple rows

Tags: wordpress

I'm inserting data to a custom table.

```
CREATE TABLE `listings_views` (
    `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `listing` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `visit_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ipaddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)
```

And I'm using $wpdb->insert like this:

```
$wpdb->insert(
        'listings_views',
        array(
            'listing'    => $jobdata->ID,
            'visit_time' => $time,
            'ipaddress'  => $visit_ip
        ),
        array(
            '%d',
            '%d',
            '%s'
        )
    );
```

While the query is running, I can see in my database that the query insert a row for each of my post. The query is NOT in a loop or else.

Any idea why?

Comment: Umm,is that query called for each post?

Comment: Strangely it does yes